# junit.framework.AssertionFailedError - Incomplete Stack Trace Given

Tags: java, junit, stack-trace

Full Disclosure: This was an assignment, it has been marked already, but I want to understand why I'm getting this error.

I'm having some issues understanding why junit.framework.AssertionFailedError is being thrown. Normally when errors occur I could at least look at the stack trace and see what is happening. In this case, the output console shows this:

```
Testcase: testIsCorrectMCQ(mr_3.myTester):  FAILED
null
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
    at mr_3.MyTester.testIsCorrectMCQ(Assign03Tester.java:207)
testIsCorrectMCQ(mr_3.MyTester):    FAILED
```

In the test result tab in NetBeans, copying the stack trace gives me:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError 
    at mr_3.myTester.testIsCorrectMCQ(myTester.java:207)
```

In the tester file, I have this:

```
@Test
public void testIsCorrectMCQ() {
    System.out.println("isCorrect of MCQ");
    MCQuestion instance = new MCQuestion(1,"Capital city of Canada is", 'A',
            "Ottawa", "Vancouver", "New York", "Toronto");
    assertFalse(instance.isCorrect("B"));
    assertTrue(instance.isCorrect("A"));  // line 207

}
```

My isCorrect method is this:

```
@Override
public boolean isCorrect(Object guess) {

    if (guess == null)
        return false;
    if (guess instanceof String) {

        String userGuess = (String)guess;
        return (userGuess.charAt(0) == this.getAnswer());
    }

    if (guess instanceof Character) {

        Character userGuess = (Character)guess;
        return (userGuess == this.getAnswer());
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Any help in understanding what is happening is greatly appreciated.

Edit 1 : My MCQuestion source code

```
public class MCQuestion extends Question {

private char answer;
private String[] options;

public MCQuestion() {

    super();
    questionType = QuestionType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE;
}

public MCQuestion(int id, String text, char answer, String... options) {

    super(id, text);
    setOptions(options);
    setAnswer(answer);
    questionType = QuestionType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE;
}

public String[] getOptions() {

    String[] getOptions = new String[this.options.length];
    System.arraycopy(this.options, 0, getOptions, 0, this.options.length);
    return getOptions;
}

public void setOptions(String... options) {

    if (options.length > 0) {
        this.options = new String[options.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {

            if (options[i].isEmpty())
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have nothing in this option");
            else
                this.options[i] = options[i];
        }

    }
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException("You have no options set");
}

public char getAnswer() {

    return this.answer;
}

public void setAnswer(char ans) {

    ans = Character.toLowerCase(ans);
    int index = ans - 97;
    if (Character.isLetter(ans) && index >= 0 && index < this.options.length)
        this.answer = ans;
    else throw new IllegalArgumentException(ans + " is not a valid answer option");
}

@Override
public boolean isCorrect(Object guess) {

    if (guess == null)
        return false;
    if (guess instanceof String) {

        String userGuess = (String)guess;
        return (userGuess.charAt(0) == this.getAnswer());
    }

    if (guess instanceof Character) {

        Character userGuess = (Character)guess;
        return (userGuess == this.getAnswer());
    }
    else return false;
}

@Override
public String toString() {

    String option = "";
    if (this.options.length == 0)
        option = "No options added, yet!";
    else {
        char index = 'a';
        for (String e: options)
            option += index + ") " + e + "\n";
    }

    return (super.toString() + "\n" + option);
}
```

}

Comment: Depending on which `assert*()` statement is on line 207, your method `isCorrect` either returning `true` even though it should return `true` or it's the other way round. So it looks like you class is not what it is supposed to do. Please edit your question to include the source code of your `MCQuestion` class and mark the line 207 in your test class.

Comment: @Progman : Updated to include where the error occurs and my MCQuestion class (Not sure if you get updates on my question, so I figured this would be the fastest way to do things)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You execute `ans = Character.toLowerCase(ans);` for whatever reason in your `setAnswer()` method before saving it in `this.answer`. This means that `(userGuess.charAt(0) == this.getAnswer())` will return false when you provide the answer in upper case, but compare it with the stored lower case character.

Depending on if you want case insensitive answers or not, you should add or remove the `Character.toLowerCase()` call to your `isCorrect()` method as well.

Comment: Thanks for that!
It looks like even the Professor did not consider that.